# Navigating to a different section of my page in react

Tags: reactjs

How can I go to a different section of a page in react. Right now, I have separated different sections in folders but not sure how to make a button that clicks to a different section in react. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Typically an app would use some routing/navigation solution. [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) is quite popular and is widely supported. As-is your question is a little off-topic (seeking recommendations on books, tools, software libraries, and more) and likely to be closed unless you edit it be a bit more specific and targeted. Have you tried implementing navigation within your app? Is it working? Etc... Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt.

Comment: there are many ways to do this, the easiest is to use react-router-hash-link, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link, but you have to get familiar with react-router first https://reactrouter.com/, this is a good practice because on the way you will learn more about react routing as a whole subject.

Comment: also you can use js function and work with Window.scrollTo() with specifying certain number of pixels from top, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo, or you can use scrollIntoView() but it's more complicated as you need to use references for elements see, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView, https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use anchor tags in react as you would in HTML.

using JSX, tag the place on the page you want to go to with an ID:

```
<h3 id="education">Education</h3>
```

Then where you want the link to be located, place an a tag using the # syntax:

```
<a href="#education">Education</a>
```

Clicking on the a tag should scroll the page to the education H3 tag.

Comment: I just tested this in my project, and it worked as expected.

Comment: How would I do this if I want to go to a different folder

Comment: For that you need to use the react-router.  React isn't like PHP or HTML where you're accessing the file system, react listens to a port and serves the same file every time, the root file of your app.  It compiles all of your code and then uses router to figure out what page to serve based on the URL.  https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start